# A nonce for each function or one for all AJAX calls?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress, nonce

I'm using nonces as WordPress uses them. It's an extra security measure, a hash that is being sent to the server that changes within ever few hours.

If that hash is not there, the request is invalidated.

The page I am working on has *many* AJAX calls (about 20 or so). Right now, I have a difference unique nonce for each one. Is that necessary? Should I just keep it with one generic "AJAX" nonce used for all the requests?

Comment: It seems like security is an important part of this question. How does the hash protect any better than a cookie would? A nonce, being a "Number used ONCE," is not what this hash represents, since you keep reusing it over and over. It can be intercepted just as easily as the user's cookie. It sounds like this adds code complexity without adding any security a cookie doesn't already provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you're doing something funky, there's not much computational overhead in having unique nonces. The added benefit is probably minimal, but I'd say it's worth leaving it the way you have it.